# c# WebClient catch Response Cookies and collect all of cookies for make a new successful requests

Tags: c#, cookies, httprequest, webclient, httpresponse

I am trying to login a website then walk around for catch some infromation and do some stuff in it.

Everything is well when the request doesnt need any cookies, but some page need cookie which is created on first request. So I should collect all of cookies in WebClient object.

I am using this code but its not enough for me. Because still I am missing all of my cookies for next request.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public CookieCollection ResponseCookies { get; set; }
    //public CookieContainer ResponseCookieContainer { get; set; }


    public CookieAwareWebClient()
      : base()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        ResponseCookies = new CookieCollection();
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        }

        return request;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)base.GetWebResponse(request);
        this.ResponseCookies = response.Cookies;


        return response;

    }
```

Here is my code for make request.

```
var loginLink ="https...."; // an Uri with username and password values as queryString

   CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
   var loginResult = client.DownloadString(loginLink);
```

I can see the result , yes I am in! login was success, but I am losting all of my cookies , and next request sending me to login page..

I should collect all of cookies in my webcilent cookieContainer. I should read Response Header for set "Set-Cookie" values to my container.

Think about this, I have 3 key in my cookies before request.

```
a = "123",
b = "asd",
c = "123"
```

and now I send a request to website and its returning me 2 cookies(one is new and one is old key with new value) back,(I can see in response Headers , in "Set-Cookie")

```
a = "123456",
d = "blabla"
```

so  I need to change key of "a"s value, and I need to add "d" key to my Cookie, because I dont want to go back to login page on my next request again...

Maybe I need a library, maybe a better WebClient Class whcih can collect all cokkies to help me to discover all pages.

I hope someone can help me. 
Best Regards!

Comment: How is the *next request* performed? Btw, you don't need a `CookieContainer` and a `CookieCollection`.  They're the same thing. You just need **one** `CookieContainer`. Don't bother about the `set-cookie` header. The `HttpWebRequest` handles this exchange on its own automatically. If you loose the Cookies then you, possibly, have `new`ed your custom `WebClient` class. I'ld suggest to directly use `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` or `HttpClient` and ditch  `WebClient`. As you can see from the lack of basic tools, it's not built for this kind of tasks (and you're not even dealing with Encoding, yet).

Comment: `HttpClient` is working good :) Thank you !